# Trying to get button to stay centered on top border of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a button.  This button needs to be centered on the divs top border, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work even after using floats.  This needs to stay responsive as well as the button should always remained centered on the top border of the div.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to to do.

[image: Button sitting on edge of div (from inside the div)]

```css
.ThankYouReview {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #F3F5FB;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ActionButton {
    border-radius: 17px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 31%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ThankYouReview" id="pnlUserCommentsDisplayed" runat="server" visible="false">

<button type="button" ID="btn" class="ActionButton" OnClick="copyReviewToClipboard();" >Click Me</button>
        <div class="Content" id="ReviewContent" runat="server" visible="true" >
            <p>This is content inside the box that will also be displayed.</p>
                    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? so that we can see where you are making mistake! We can't assume anything.

Comment: I just did, sorry I didn't include that in my original post!

Comment: Hi.. Position absolute will help you. https://jsfiddle.net/86bfp0mo/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```
.ThankYouReview {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #F3F5FB;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:black
}

.ActionButton {
    border-radius: 17px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1em;
}
```